# Probability of first collision with replacement

Tags: probability-distributions

Suppose I have a bag of `N` balls, each labeled with a distinct integer. The experiment starts when I draw a ball from the bag, record its label, and then return the ball back to the bag. I repeat this step until I draw a ball that I have already drawn before. Let `X` be the number of balls I drew in the experiment. Let `P` be the probability distribution of `X`.

Is there a name to this probability function `P`?

Is there a closed form for `P`?

Actually, I would be satisfied if there is a closed form for `E[X]` and `Var[X]`.

Please help.

Comment: This is a variant of the birthday problem. It looks like even the wikipedia article on this has the information you're asking for.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103892/solving-a-modified-birthday-problem-at-a-glance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$P(X)=(X-1)N^{1-X}\frac{(N-1)!}{(N+1-X)!}$, for $X=2,3,\ldots N+1$.

Comment: I tried a few cases with small N and X, and this looks good. By the way, calculating the expected value seems difficult because of the factorial. I don't suppose I could trouble you further for some suggestion how E[X] and Var[X] could be solved?

Comment: I'm sorry, no simple closed form expression for the moments; but they can be calculated easily, E[X]=2,5/2,26/9,103/32,2194/625,1223/324,  and Var[X]=0,1/4,44/81,879/1024,463864/390625,160235/104976 for N=1,2,3,4,5,6. What more can you want...?

Comment: I was trying to use `E[X] = f(N)` as an estimator to estimate the number of objects in a set of unknown size `N`: suppose after conducting a large set of experiments I get an empirical average `y`, I can then solve for `N` in the equation `y = f(N)`. So, I was hoping there's a closed form for `f`.

Answer (score 1):

There's no closed form for this expectation. However, you can get good approximations. One common way to do this is with generating functions. Herb Wilf's [book](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) is an excellent reference.

As noted, the probability that the first collision occurs on the $n$th draw with  $m$ balls is $p_n=d_{n-1}\frac{n-1}m$, where $d_n=\frac{m!}{m^n (m-n)!}$. Consider the ordinary generating function $D(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}d_nx^n$. Then the expected number of draws to get a collision would be $\langle p\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^{m+1} n\cdot p_n$ or, in terms of the generating function,
$\langle p\rangle=\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(xD(x))|_{x=1}$.

The generating function $D(x)$ is not summable. However, its exponential counterpart is: $E(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{m}\frac{d_n}{ n!}x^n=(1+x/m)^m$. The ordinary and exponential generating functions are related by the Laplace transform, $D(x)=\frac 1x\int_0^\infty e^{-t/x}E(t)dt$. Differentiating under the integral twice  and then evaluating at $x=1$, we get $\langle p\rangle=\frac 1m\int_0^\infty e^{-t}(t^2-2t)(1+t/m)^mdt$. The dominant part in this integral comes from the $t^2$  term. So, $\langle p\rangle\approx\frac 1m\int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^2(1+t/m)^m dt$, and substituting $u=t/m$, we get $\langle p\rangle\approx m^2\int_0^\infty e^{m(-u+\log(1+u))}u^2 du$. This integral can be nicely approximated with Laplace's method, where the exponent $-u+\log(1+u)$ is replaced with its second order Taylor series about its maximum (at $u=0$), which turns out to be just $-u^2/2$. So, $\langle p\rangle\approx m^2\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2 m/2}u^2du=\sqrt{{\pi m}/2}$.

If you need greater accuracy or if you want to consider higher moments of the distribution, you can always consider the other terms in the first integral representation of $\langle p\rangle$ and higher order terms in the Laplace's method. Another avenue to analyze this expectation, as suggested in the wikipedia article on the birthday problem, is to learn about the Ramanujan $Q$-function.